# Logorithms on a first level learning

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Solve log$_{5x-1}$ $4$ $=$ $1/3$

$(5x-1)^{1/3}$=4

$((5x-1)^{1/3})^3$ = $4^3$

$5x-1=64$

$5x=65$

$13$

I am not sure where to go with this. I learned some things about logs before my class ended for the year. I just wanted to expand on my knowledge. This is more advance than what I am use to doing. Can someone please show me.

Answer (score 3):

If I didn't understand all of the steps, I would try to include all steps. One step that is missing is explicitly raising the base to the power of the LHS and RHS respectively.
$$\log_{5x-1}4 = 1/3$$
$$(5x-1)^{\log_{5x-1}4} = (5x-1)^{1/3}$$

We know that $a^{\log_aY}=Y$, similarly our equation becomes

$$4 = (5x-1)^{1/3}$$
Now if $4 = (5x-1)^{1/3}$ then
$$4\cdot4\cdot4 = (5x-1)^{1/3}\cdot (5x-1)^{1/3}\cdot (5x-1)^{1/3}$$
$$4^3 = (5x-1)^{1/3+1/3+1/3}$$
$$64 = (5x-1)^{1} = 5x-1$$

If you need a little refresher on the rules of exponents, try looking at http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html

Answer (score 2):

It is easier if after the second line you cube both sides.

Comment: Can you check if this is correct?

Comment: @carson You can check this by replacing your value into the original equation:  $ \ \log_{5 \cdot 13 \ - \ 1} \ 4 \ = \ \log_{64} \ 4 \ $ .  It is certainly the case that $ \ 64^{1/3} \ = \ 4 \ $ , so $ \ \log_{64} \ 4 \ = \ \frac{1}{3} \ $ , meaning that you have the correct value for $ \ x \ $ .